# Coloring a graph - chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory

Proof, that in any vertex coloring of graph $G$ using $\chi(G)$ coloros, there is a vertex of every color such that it has a neighbour in every color.

My idea is: let's assume that there is a color, which doesn't have a vertex with neighbour in every color. So let's change his color to a new, legal one and continue changing colors of other vertexes of the original color. This way we would remove one color, and thus color the graph using $\chi(G)-1$ colors, which is impossible.

It is important to notice, that changing the colors of previous vertex won't influence changing color of future vertex, as they can't be connected.

Comment: This seems like a full proof to me.

Comment: Let me point out that the question is ambigious. There exist graphs $G$ coloured with $\chi(G)$ colours for whcih there exist a colour $i$ such that every vertex $v$ of colour $i$ has some colour missing in its neighbourhood $N(v)$.     The question should be "Prove that for any optimal vertex colouring  $f$ of a graph $G$, for every two distinct colours $i,j$, there exist two adjacent vertices $u,v$ such that $f(u)=i$ and $f(v)=j$"